# AngularJS Error: $injector:unpr Unknown Provider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service

I'm trying to build my own service by following the example in the documentation for the factory methodology.  I think I've done something wrong however because I continue to get the unknown provider error.  This is my code for my app including the declaration, configuration and factory definition.

**EDIT 
I've now added all of the files to help troubleshoot**

**EDIT
The full details of the error are below the issues appears to be with getSettings, as it's looking for getSettingsProvider and cannot find it**

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16/$injector/unpr?    p0=getSettingsProvider%20%3C-%20getSettings
    at Error (native)
    at http://localhost/sw/selfservice/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:6:450
    at http://localhost/sw/selfservice/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:35:431
    at Object.c [as get] (http://localhost/sw/selfservice/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:34:13)
    at http://localhost/sw/selfservice/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:35:499
    at c (http://localhost/sw/selfservice/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:34:13)
    at d (http://localhost/sw/selfservice/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:34:230)
    at Object.instantiate (http://localhost/sw/selfservice/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:34:394)
    at http://localhost/sw/selfservice/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:66:112
    at http://localhost/sw/selfservice/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:53:14 angular.js:9778
(anonymous function) angular.js:9778
(anonymous function) angular.js:7216
h.$apply angular.js:12512
(anonymous function) angular.js:1382
d angular.js:3869
$b.c angular.js:1380
$b angular.js:1394
Wc angular.js:1307
(anonymous function) angular.js:21459
a angular.js:2509
(anonymous function) angular.js:2780
q angular.js:330
c
```

These are all of the files I have in my app currently

app.JS

```
//Initialize angular module include route dependencies

var app = angular.module("selfservice", ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
   $routeProvider
       .when('/', {
           templateUrl:"partials/login.html",
           controller:"login"
       });
});






app.factory('getSettings', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q) {
    return function (type) {
        var q = $q.defer();
        $http.get('models/settings.json').success(function (data) {
            q.resolve(function() {
                var settings = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                return settings[type];
            });
        });

        return q.promise;
    };
}]);
```

And here is how I am using this service in my controller

controller.JS

```
app.controller("globalControl", ['$scope','getSettings', function ($scope,getSettings) {
    var loadSettings = getSettings('global');
    loadSettings.then(function(val) {
        $scope.settings = val;
    });

}]);


app.controller("login", ['$scope', function ($scope) {

    return ""



}]);
```

directives.js

```
app.directive('watchResize', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'M',
        link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
            scope.spacer = (window.innerWidth < 1025) ? '' : 'large-3';
            scope.button = (window.innerWidth < 1025) ? '' : 'large-6';
            angular.element(window).on('resize', function(){
                scope.$apply(function(){
                    scope.spacer = (window.innerWidth < 1025) ? '' : 'large-3';
                    scope.button = (window.innerWidth < 1025) ? '' : 'large-6';
                });
            });
        }
    };
});
```

And if it's pertinent here's the HTML

```
<html class="no-js" lang="en" ng-app="selfservice" ng-controller="globalControl">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
     <title>{{settings.title}}</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css" />
    <script src="bower_components/modernizr/modernizr.js"></script>
      <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
       <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
       <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="js/app.js"></script>
      <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
      <script src="js/directives.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="template">
        <header id="header">
            <img src="{{settings.logo}}" alt="{{settings.logoDescription}}"/>
        </header>

        <div id="view">
            <ng-view></ng-view>
        </div>

    </div>

    <script src="bower_components/foundation/js/foundation.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        //initialize foundation
        $(document).foundation();

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?  I have done my best to follow the documentation, and looking through SO most of the related issues are much more in depth, and more difficult for me to understand.  This is my first time creating a service.

Comment: Is the error providing you with the unknown providers name?  Typically there is a string value in the error.

Comment: In your console you should be able to click on the unknown provider error message, which will take you to an Angular page giving you more information about the error. It could be helpful for you to post that info in your question.

Comment: Sorry for not having all the details initially, I was trying to keep the question concise, however I have now provided all the details I have about the issue

Comment: For anyone coming across this problem (first in Google), this answer to a similar question fixed it for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25193243/556006

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Your angular module needs to be initialized properly. The global object `app` needs to be defined and initialized correctly to inject the service.

Please see below sample code for reference:

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('SampleApp',['ngRoute']); //You can inject the dependencies within the square bracket    

app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
      templateUrl:"partials/login.html",
      controller:"login"
    });

  $locationProvider
    .html5Mode(true);
}]);

app.factory('getSettings', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q) {
  return {
    //Code edited to create a function as when you require service it returns object by default so you can't return function directly. That's what understand...
    getSetting: function (type) { 
      var q = $q.defer();
      $http.get('models/settings.json').success(function (data) {
        q.resolve(function() {
          var settings = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
          return settings[type];
        });
      });
      return q.promise;
    }
  }
}]);

app.controller("globalControl", ['$scope','getSettings', function ($scope,getSettings) {
  //Modified the function call for updated service
  var loadSettings = getSettings.getSetting('global');
  loadSettings.then(function(val) {
    $scope.settings = val;
  });
}]);
```

Sample HTML code should be like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head lang="en">
        <title>Sample Application</title>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="SampleApp" ng-controller="globalControl">
        <div>
            Your UI elements go here
        </div>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Please note that the controller is not binding to an HTML tag but to the body tag. Also, please try to include your custom scripts at end of the HTML page as this is a standard practice to follow for performance reasons.

I hope this will solve your basic injection issue.

Comment: I cannot see what you've done in your sample that I've not done and shown in this question, can you be more specific please?

Comment: I have updated the answer with appropriate comments. I hope this will resolve your issue.

Comment: Thanks, you save me, I spent 12 hours searching and the problem was that `['$routeProvider',` was missing between `app.config` and `function`

Answer (score 47):

also one of the popular reasons maybe you miss to include the service file in your page

```
<script src="myservice.js"></script>
```

Comment: Its one of those face palm moments when you realise you forgot to include the file in your bundle.

Answer (score 10):

```
app.factory('getSettings', ['$http','$q' /*here!!!*/,function($http, $q) {
```

you need to declare ALL your dependencies OR none and you forgot to declare $q .

edit:

controller.js : login, dont return ""

Comment: I can see that I missed that, so I've updated my code to include it but still getting the same error.  I've updated the question to give a better view of all my code

Comment: did you put the content of app.js,directive.js and service.js ? because i cant guess what's inside these files.

Comment: I have added all of the files

Answer (score 9):

This error is also appears when one accidntally injects $scope into theirs factory:

```
angular.module('m', [])
    .factory('util', function ($scope) { // <-- this '$scope' gives 'Unknown provider' when one attempts to inject 'util'
       // ...
    });
```

Comment: this helped a lot

Answer (score 3):

Spent a few hours trying to solve the same. This is how I did it:

app.js:

```
var myApp = angular.module( 'myApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource', 'CustomServices'] );
```

CustomServices is a new module I created and placed in a separate file called services.js

_Layout.cshtml:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/app.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/services/services.js"></script>
```

services.js:

```
var app = angular.module('CustomServices', []); 
app.factory( 'GetPeopleList', ['$http', '$log','$q', function ( $http, $log, $q )
{
    //Your code here
}
```

app.js

```
myApp.controller( 'mainController', ['$scope', '$http', '$route', '$routeParams', '$location', 'GetPeopleList', function ( $scope, $http, $route, $routeParams, $location, GetPeopleList )
```

You have to bind your service to your new module in the services.js file AND of course you have to use that new module in the creation of your main app module (app.js) AND also declare the use of the service in the controller you want to use it in.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting this problem and it turned out I had included my controller both in ui.router and in the html template  as in

```
.config(['$stateProvider',
  function($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('dashboard', {
      url: '/dashboard',
      templateUrl: 'dashboard/views/index.html',
      controller: 'DashboardController'
    });
  }
]);
```

and

```
<section data-ng-controller="DashboardController">
```

Answer (score 1):

Please "include" both Controller and the module(s) where the controller and the functions called in the Controller are.

```
module(theModule);
```

Answer (score 0):

@ user2310334
I just tried this, a VERY basic example:

HTML file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">

<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.6/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.6/angular-route.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="./app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div ng-controller="MailDetailCtrl">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The javascript file:

```
var myApp= angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

myApp.factory('mailService' , function () {
return {
    getData : function(){
      var employees = [{name: 'John Doe', id: '1'},
        {name: 'Mary Homes', id: '2'},
        {name: 'Chris Karl', id: '3'}
      ];

      return employees;
    }
  };

});


myApp.controller('MailDetailCtrl',['$scope', 'mailService', function($scope, mailService) {
  alert(mailService.getData()[0].name);
}]);
```

And it works. Try it.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that you load controller **outside`app.config`**. The following code may cause this error:

```
app.config(["$stateProvider", "$urlRouterProvider", function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
       var AuthCtrl = require('components/auth/AuthCtrl'); //NOTICE HERE
       $stateProvider.state('login',{
            url: "/users/login",
            templateUrl: require("components/auth/login.tpl.html"),
            controller: AuthCtrl // ERROR
        })
}))
```

To fix this error, we must move AuthCtrl to **outside`app.config`**:

```
var AuthCtrl = require('components/auth/AuthCtrl'); //NOTICE HERE
app.config(["$stateProvider", "$urlRouterProvider", function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
       $stateProvider.state('login',{
            url: "/users/login",
            templateUrl: require("components/auth/login.tpl.html"),
            controller: AuthCtrl // WORK
        });
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I added a new service (file) to my app. That new service is injected in an existing controller.  I did not miss new service dependency injection into that existing controller and did not declare my app module no more than one place. The same exception is thrown when I re-run my web app and my browser cache **is not reset** with a new service file codes. I simply refreshed my browser to get that new service file for browser cache, and the problem was gone.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is the first Stackoverflow question that appears on Google when searching for `Error: $injector:unpr Unknown Provider` I'll add this here.

Make sure that in your index.html any modules/dependencies are not being loaded after they are needed.

For example in my code `customFactory.factory.js` begins like this:

```
angular
   .module("app.module1")
   .factory("customFactory", customFactory);
```

However the index.html looked like this:

```
    <script src="/src/client/app/customFactory.factory.js"></script>
    <script src="/src/client/app/module1.module.js"></script>
```

Where it should've really looked like this:

```
    <script src="/src/client/app/module1.module.js"></script>
    <script src="/src/client/app/customFactory.factory.js"></script>
```

Since `customFactory.factory.js` is declared as part of `module1`, it needs to be loaded before `customFactory`

Answer (score 0):

I got this error writing a Jasmine unit test. I had the line:

```
angular.injector(['myModule'])
```

It needed to be:

```
angular.injector(['ng', 'myModule'])
```

Answer (score -2):

When you are using ui-router, you should not use ng-controller anywhere. Your controllers are automatically instantiated for a ui-view when their appropriate states are activated.

Comment: This isn't strictly true. It's just good practice for views that use a single controller. What if you wanted to load a view that uses multiple controllers?