# AngularJS [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I am trying to inject a service into controller, and i am getting following error:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: employeeServiceProvider <- employeeService
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.17/$injector/unpr?p0=employeeServiceProvider%20%3C-%20employeeService
    at http://localhost:9082/angularJSDemo/js/lib/angular.js:78:12
    at http://localhost:9082/angularJSDemo/js/lib/angular.js:3894:19
    at Object.getService [as get]
```

Here is [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/RSf9HyxyXBC9GvL6yQSB) for code. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you use angular.module twice, the second time you have to leave out the second parameter otherwise it will overwrite the module. angular.module("demoApp").factory()

Comment: Thanks Zack, you are right, it is working now.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are repeating `angular.module('demoApp', [])` everywhere it will clear out any entities attached to the module that has been added already and recreate the module, after module initialization you should  use its reference or just use `angular.module('demoApp').service...` using this will retrieve the module to which you can add services etc...

```
var module = angular.module('demoApp', []).controller('employeeController', function($scope, employeeService) {
    $scope.employees = employeeService.getData();
});


module.factory('employeeService', function (){
    return {
        getData : function(){
            var employees = [{name: 'John Doe', id: '1'}, 
                                {name: 'Mary Homes', id: '2'},
                                {name: 'Chris Karl', id: '3'}
                                ];

            return employees;
        }
    };

});
```

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/O0xbq5lMamDYpKQe9gTD?p=preview)**

[Quote from Doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module#creation-versus-retrieval):-

> Beware that using angular.module('myModule', []) will create the module myModule and overwrite any existing module named myModule. Use angular.module('myModule') to retrieve an existing module.

Comment: My bad, the service and controller are in two different files, when i was copying to plunker, i have accidentally pasted them in one file. I have corrected the plunker. And I have got my answer from  Zack Argyle, thanks a lot.

Comment: @JavaKB ofcourse both the answers i guess covers all the scenarios. `angular.module('demoApp').service`. It does not mean `.service` can only be a service, it can be factory as well. :) Also quote from documentation is also explicit enough i thought

Comment: But, @PSL, what happens if i wanna have service and controller in separate files? It isn't possible?

Comment: @OscarCalderon ofcourse it is possible and it is a common pattern. Use module getter syntax. angular.module("myapp").controller....

Comment: damn, got caught by that mistake too, thanks for help PSL

Answer (score 3):

I don't know the reason why you are repeating the module (demoApp) creation. On line 6, you attempted to create demoApp module which is the cause of your problem. Your code should look like this:

```
angular.module('demoApp', [])
.controller('employeeController', function($scope, employeeService) {
    $scope.employees = employeeService.getData();
})
.factory('employeeService', function (){
    return {
        getData : function(){
            var employees = [{name: 'John Doe', id: '1'}, 
                                {name: 'Mary Homes', id: '2'},
                                {name: 'Chris Karl', id: '3'}
                                ];

            return employees;
        }
    };

});
```

Or

```
var demoApp=angular.module('demoApp', [])
.controller('employeeController', function($scope, employeeService) {
    $scope.employees = employeeService.getData();
});

demoApp.factory('employeeService', function (){
    return {
        getData : function(){
            var employees = [{name: 'John Doe', id: '1'}, 
                                {name: 'Mary Homes', id: '2'},
                                {name: 'Chris Karl', id: '3'}
                                ];

            return employees;
        }
    };

});
```

Instead of

```
angular.module('demoApp', []).controller('employeeController', function($scope, employeeService) {
    $scope.employees = employeeService.getData();
});


angular.module('demoApp', []).factory('employeeService', function (){
    return {
        getData : function(){
            var employees = [{name: 'John Doe', id: '1'}, 
                                {name: 'Mary Homes', id: '2'},
                                {name: 'Chris Karl', id: '3'}
                                ];

            return employees;
        }
    };

});
```

If you like to keep your Controllers in a separate file (this is RECOMMENDED) from the Service you can consider have something like this as your abcController.js

```
angular.module('demoApp', ['demoApp.employeeController']).controller('employeeController', function($scope, employeeService) {
    $scope.employees = employeeService.getData();
});
```

and xyzService.js

```
angular.module('demoApp.employeeController', []).factory('employeeService', function (){
    return {
        getData : function(){
            var employees = [{name: 'John Doe', id: '1'}, 
                                {name: 'Mary Homes', id: '2'},
                                {name: 'Chris Karl', id: '3'}
                                ];

            return employees;
        }
    };

});
```

Comment: My bad, the service and controller are in two different files, when i was copying to plunker, i have accidentally pasted them in one file. I have corrected the plunker. And I have got my answer from  Zack Argyle, thanks a lot.

Comment: You are welcome. You can still do one up/down vote as you might wish to. at least for the effort