# AuglarFire Authenticating With Routers throw unknown provider error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

So I am following the firebase doc here [authentication with Routers](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/user-auth.html#section-routers). Instead, I use Ionic / ui-router and has abstract view and actual view with controller. Here is the structure:

```
.state('auth', {
  url: "/auth",
  abstract: true,
  templateUrl: "app/auth/auth.html",
  resolve: {
    "currentAuth": ["Auth", function(Auth){
      // $waitForAuth returns a promise so the resolve waits for it to complete
      return Auth.$waitForAuth();
    }]
  }
})
.state('auth.signin', {
  url: '/signin',
  views: {
    'auth-signin': {
      templateUrl: 'app/auth/auth-signin.html',
      controller: 'SignInCtrl'
    }
  }
})
.state('home', {
  cache: false,
    abstract: true,
    url: "/home",
    templateUrl: "app/home/home.html",
  controller: 'homeTabCtrl',
  resolve: {
    "currentAuth": ["Auth", function(Auth){
      // $requireAuth returns a promise so the resolve waits for it to complete
      // If the promise is rejected, it will throw a $stateChangeError (see above)
      return Auth.$requireAuth();
    }]
  }
})

.state('home.courses', {
  cache: false,
  url: "/courses",
  views: {
    "tab-courses": {
      templateUrl: "app/home/courses.html",
      controller: "courseCtrl"
    }
  }
})
```

So it works fine. When I go to home.courses without logging in, I redirect to auth.signin. But I want to get the currentAuth return object/promise inside the SignInCtrl. So when user is logged in, if they go to auth.signin state, it will redirect them to home.courses instead. I follow the doc instruction to inject the currentAuth in controller like so:

```
(function () {
'use strict';
angular.module("myApp").controller('SignInCtrl', ['currentAuth', '$scope', '$rootScope', SignInCtrl]);

function SignInCtrl(currentAuth, $scope, $rootScope){
    console.log (currentAuth);
}

})();
```

It throw error:

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: currentAuthProvider <- currentAuth <- SignInCtrl

I did the same thing as the docs example and try to get the currentAuth promise object (in order to use if statement to redirect user to home.courses if currentAuth is not NULL). But it does not work :( Please help firebase team.

**UPDATE:**

According Kato, I will not be able to access the currentAuth promise. So what is the conventional way to see if user is logged in already if they are in route /auth/signin/ and redirect them to /home/courses/ route?

Comment: Have a look to this query http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25193226/angularjs-injectorunpr-unknown-provider

Answer (score 1):

The error is pretty informative; this is routes 101 and has been covered dozens of times on Stack Overflow. The key here is understanding that `currentAuth` is not a service or module (you've attempted to include it as a module and a service here), but is injected by the resolve method when a specific route is invoked.

currentAuth is therefore not available to `/signin` path, since there is no `resolve` for that route. It's available to the "home" route because of this resolve:

```
  resolve: {
    "currentAuth": ["Auth", function(Auth){
```

Thus, you can't also use that data in /signin unless you also create a resolve for the route which injects it there, which should be superfluous since you only send them to /signin if authData is null.

Comment: Sorry I am pretty flesh with UI-Routes. So if currentAuth is not available, what can I do to create the condition that when user is Logged in, if they visit route auth/signin, it will redirect them back to /home/courses route?

Comment: Add a resolve to that route just like you have on the home route. You need to begin by reading the docs on routes and understanding how they work. Angular covers these in detail.