# Angular Error: $injector:unpr Unknown Provider when separating files

Tags: javascript, angularjs, factory

I have the following code and it works fine:

app.main.js:

```
angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.router'])
.factory('_', function() {
  return window._;
});

angular.module('app').run(['$route', '$rootScope', '$location', function ($route, $rootScope, $location) {
    var original = $location.path;
    $location.path = function (path, reload) {
        if (reload === false) {
            var lastRoute = $route.current;
            var un = $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function () {
                $route.current = lastRoute;
                un();
            });
        }
        return original.apply($location, [path]);
    };
}]);
```

bservice:

```
angular.module('app')
  .service('bService', ['$http', '_', function($http, _) { ...
```

But when I try to separate de factory to a different file I get the Angular Error: $injector:unpr Unknown Provider. This file looks like this:

```
angular.module('app').factory('_', function() {
  return window._;
});
```

I also made sure that the factory file is included.

Thanks

EDIT

Full error:
Unknown provider: _Provider

Comment: Can you post the full error? Which provider is unknown?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS Error: $injector:unpr Unknown Provider](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23942356/angularjs-error-injectorunpr-unknown-provider)

Comment: Did you include the new file in your HTML?

Comment: Yes I use gulp to merge all js files.

Comment: Are you including the `_` factory before `bService`? The order may be important since `bService` depends on `_`.

Comment: I guess gulp didn't like the name `factorys` in the folder structure ( Wrong spelled ). If i change it to something like `fact` everything works fine. Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

I use gulp for the file merges. So everything is in one file.

Gulp didn't like the name `factorys`. Because of this my factory became damaged in the main .js file.

The solution was to rename the folder to anything els then factorys.